# multiple column style with python openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to specify the style of the columns in the table. If I select only one column as the style, it works, but if I want to specify more than one of the columns. I get this error message: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'style'

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, Alignment, Border, Side, colors
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle


path = "my xlsx file path"
workbook = load_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook.active
sheet

shetnames_str = workbook.sheetnames
print(shetnames_str)
print(sheet)

dimensions = sheet.dimensions

print("Dimenzió: "+dimensions)

selected_sheetname = workbook["Munka1"]
#Style definition

highlight = NamedStyle(name="highlight")
bd = Side(style='thin', color="000000")
highlight.border = Border(left=bd, top=bd, right=bd, bottom=bd)

for cell in sheet["A:B"]:
    print(cell)
    cell.style = highlight

workbook.save(filename="moddedxlsx.xlsx")
```

Comment: sheet"A"] knows that it is only one column wide so just returns a list of cells but sheet["A:B"] must return a list of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, Alignment, Border, Side, colors
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle


path = "C:\\Users\\Jutasig\\Documents\\python_jegyzetek\\Dev\\Style\\master_xls_style\\szamla.xlsx"
workbook = load_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook.active
sheet

shetnames_str = workbook.sheetnames
print(shetnames_str)
print(sheet)

dimensions = "\""+sheet.dimensions+"\""

print("Dimenzió: "+dimensions)

selected_sheetname = workbook["Munka1"]
#Style definition

def set_border(ws, cell_range):
    border = Border(left=Side(border_style='thin', color='000000'),
                right=Side(border_style='thin', color='000000'),
                top=Side(border_style='thin', color='000000'),
                bottom=Side(border_style='thin', color='000000'))

    rows = ws[cell_range]
    for row in rows:
        for cell in row:
            cell.border = border

set_border(sheet, sheet.dimensions)


workbook.save(filename="moddedxlsx.xlsx")
```